# Using Python - Comparison between 2 Files and Printing the Result in the form including Mismatches in a formatted way

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My files are as below:

File 1:

```
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL5

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5S'|'5042449536906016501541'

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701550'

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:23'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701555'
```

File 2:

```
COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL5

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5Q'|'5042449536906016501541'

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701550'

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701555'
```

Here Primary Key is my 5th Column.

1. The output I want in as follows after the Comparison of the 2 Files:

   ```
   PrimaryKey|Column|File1Value|File2Value
   '5042449536906016501541'|COL4|'1A3LA7015L5S'|'1A3LA7015L5Q'
   '5042449603146028701555'|COL2|'2017-09-01 00:19:23'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'
   ```
2. It should list out the Mismatches along the Columns it has happened in the format as given above
3. Tried with the Below Code, but this only works when it has only similar number of rows in both files and finds out only cell level mismatches.. but i want to handle the missing in source file , missing in target file and also handle the duplicates in the files then from the common ones find out the mismatches.. plzz help

   ```
   import sys
   import csv
   import datetime
   import time
   import os
   from operator import itemgetter
   if len(sys.argv) !=3 :    
     print "invalid params"
     exit
   elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
     ts = time.time()
     st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
     os.makedirs(st)
     os.chdir(st)
     d = '|'    # we can change delimiter here
     rslt = open('Comp_Result','w')
     stgt = open('sort_tgt','wr')
     read1 = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1],'rb'),delimiter=d)
     read2 = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[2],'rb'),delimiter=d)
     sort_src = sorted(read1, key=itemgetter(0))
     sort_tgt = sorted(read2, key=itemgetter(0))
     f=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
     reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=d)
     num_cols = len(next(reader)) # Read first line and count columns
     f.seek(0)
     num_lines=0
     rslt.write('Key_col|col_num|src_value|tgt_value')
     rslt.write('\n ********************************************\n')
     for trg_line in sort_tgt:
       for i in range(0, num_cols):
         stgt.write(trg_line[i])
         stgt.write('|')
       stgt.write('\n')
       num_lines = num_lines + 1
     stgt.close()
     stgt_file=open('sort_tgt','r')
     read_tgt = csv.reader(stgt_file,delimiter=d)
     check_point=1
     stgt_file.seek(0)
     tgt_line = next(read_tgt)
     #stgt_file.seek(0)
    for src_line in sort_src:  
       while(src_line[0]>=tgt_line[0] and check_point <= num_lines):
         check_point = check_point + 1
         if  src_line[0]==tgt_line[0]:
            #check_point = check_point + 1
            for i in range(1, num_cols):
              if src_line[i]!=tgt_line[i]:
                   col_num = str(i + 1)
               rslt.write(src_line[0])
               rslt.write('|')
               rslt.write(col_num)
               rslt.write('|')
               rslt.write(src_line[i])
               rslt.write('|')
               rslt.write(tgt_line[i])
               rslt.write('\n')
         prev_line = tgt_line
         if check_point <= num_lines:
           tgt_line = next(read_tgt)

     print '\n\n**************************** \n comparison done,         \n************************** \n Results are in Comp_Result file at below     folder:'
     print st
     print ' \n\n'
   ```

Comment: This is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959130/using-python-comparison-between-2-files-and-printing-the-result-in-a-desired-f) and I don't see any code. Please edit your question. It got 5 down votes and was put on hold for a reason.

Comment: sorry forgot to put the code i added it now

Comment: There's a built in module called `diff` or something like that available for doing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `pandas` and `numpy` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#1
csv_1 = '48005038-1.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=csv_1, sep='|', index_col=4)

csv_2 = '48005038-2.csv'
df2 = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=csv_2, sep='|', index_col=4)

#2
ne_stacked = (df1 != df2).stack()
changed = ne_stacked[ne_stacked]
changed.index.names = ['COL5', 'col']

#3
diff = np.where(df1 != df2)
changed_from = df1.values[diff]
changed_to = df2.values[diff]

#4
diff = pd.DataFrame({'from': changed_from, 'to': changed_to}, index=changed.index)
print(diff)
```

1. Read your csv files as a pandas dataframe
2. To get the different column per row
3. Get the before, after changed.
4. Convert the diff data back to dataframe with the index we get from step#2.

The output would be:

```
                                                from                     to
COL5                     col
'5042449536906016501541' COL4         '1A3LA7015L5S'         '1A3LA7015L5Q'
'5042449603146028701555' COL2  '2017-09-01 00:19:23'  '2017-09-01 00:19:20'
```

that I think you can convert to the format you want easily.